# Error glassfish al desplegar mi proyecto en Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

Hoola, he googleado bastante y no he podido hallar una solución.

Cuando hago un `run as` de mi proyecto en eclipse, me aparece el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a activar esta opción, ya que lo he visto en otro post de Stack Overflow, pero nada, no hay manera.

Si necesitáis cualquier información más, no dudéis en pedírmela.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito ayuda, por favor, gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

El error parece indicar que intentas inyectar un Bean (@Autowired) que no está registrado en el contenedor de beans (mira orderService, adminController)

Comment: He quitado el @Autowired y sigue sin funcionar :(, ¿tienes alguna otra idea?